# Base the Install Directory on the ProductCode

Tags: wix, wix3.10

I'm fairly new to Wix.

I started with this example :

https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/09/real-world-example-wix-msi-application-installer/

He has a compute routine that figured out the INSTALLDIR, using variables (actually, locale information as seen below).

```
<!-- All folders from here on are relative to their parent. -->

<Directory Id="ProgramFilesHK" Name="!(loc.ManufacturerName)">

  <!-- INSTALLDIR is a property name. We need it later for the UI (to be able to change the install dir. -->
  <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="!(loc.ApplicationName)">
```

Which (in the example) resolves to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Helge Klein\uberAgent\

I'm trying to make the ProductCode the (last) subfolder of the all the nested subfolders.

Aka, I want:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Helge Klein\{22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222}\

I found this:

[Obtaining generated ProductCode as a variable in Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884019/obtaining-generated-productcode-as-a-variable-in-wix)

So I attempted to change the code to:

```
        <!-- INSTALLDIR is a property name. We need it later for the UI (to be able to change the install dir. -->
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="[PRODUCTCODE]">
```

and also

```
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="[ProductCode]">
```

Unfortunately, that gives me

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apps\CCT\[ProductCode]\
```

and not the value of the Guid for the actual ProductCode

Why am I doing this?

I am doing Instance installs, and

```
  <Property Id="INSTANCEID" Value="0"/>
  <InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
    <Instance Id="I01" ProductCode="{22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222}" ProductName="My Product 01"/>
    <Instance Id="I02" ProductCode="{33333333-3333-4f1a-9E88-874745E9224C}" ProductName="My Product 02"/>
    <Instance Id="I03" ProductCode="{44444444-4444-5494-843B-BC07BBC022DB}" ProductName="My Product 03"/>
  </InstanceTransforms>
```

and this article

http://ysdevlog.blogspot.com/2011/08/revisited-multiple-instance.html

says this:

> For the file data, this means installing the files of each instance to
>   a different location – the path containing instance ID as its part
>   fits best.

How can I "get" the ProductCode in this "compute" install-directory logic?

Thanks.

Non available tag: Wix version 3.10

***Note about the duplicate question "tag".***

This is NOT the same as [Wix Installer - Create Folder hierarchy based on Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478566/wix-installer-create-folder-hierarchy-based-on-property) because there the Macro value actually resolves.

***The issue here is that the Macro value does not resolve.***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wix Installer - Create Folder hierarchy based on Property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478566/wix-installer-create-folder-hierarchy-based-on-property)

Comment: I added a comment on how the other question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe use a custom action to update INSTALLDIR with [ProductCode]

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this to your wxs and see if that works?

```
<CustomAction Id="SetInstallDir" Property="INSTALLDIR" 
              Value="[PRODUCTCODE]" 
              Execute="firstSequence" />
```

And within the `<InstallExecuteSequence>` tag:

```
<Custom Action="SetInstallDir" Before="CostFinalize">INSTALLDIR=""</Custom>
```